# error when starting the spark shell

Tags: apache-spark

I just downloaded the latest version of spark and when I started the spark shell I got the following error:

```
java.net.BindException: Failed to bind to: /192.168.1.254:0: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:393)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:389)

...
...

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
...
...
<console>:10: error: not found: value sqlContext
       import sqlContext.implicits._
              ^
<console>:10: error: not found: value sqlContext
       import sqlContext.sql
              ^
```

Is there something that I missed in setting up spark?

Comment: By running 'spark-shell', it creates the directory \tmp\hive under C:, had the same issue\ error and it turned out to be an issue with the permissions to that folder. Simply moved it under your %HADOOP_HOME%\bin and restart the cmd as administrator. It worked like a charm for me after going through any possible fix recommended on stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the Spark env variable `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` to a local IP address.

In my case, I was running Spark on an Amazon EC2 Linux instance. `spark-shell` stopped working, with an error message similar to yours. I was able to fix it by adding a setting like the following to the Spark config file `spark-env.conf`.

`export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=172.30.43.105`

Could also set it in ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc.

Also check host settings in `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 1):

See [SPARK-8162](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8162).

It looks like it only affects 1.4.1 and 1.5.0 - you're probably best off running the latest release (1.4.0 at time of writing).

Comment: I have tried the prebuilt versions of 1.4.0, 1.3.1, and 1.3.0 and they all have the same error. I am using Java 7 on osx.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue. First got to .bashrc and put

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=172.30.43.105
```

then goto

```
cd $HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

then run the following command

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

This just switches your safemode of namenode off.

Then delete the metastore_db folder from the spark home folder or /bin. It will be generally be in a folder from which you generally start a spark session.

then I ran my spark-shell using this

```
spark-shell --master "spark://localhost:7077"
```

and voila I didnot get the sqlContext.implicits._ error.