# spark fail in windows: <console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop2

I install spark on windows, but it failed to run showing the error below:

```
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.implicits._
                ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.sql
                ^
```

I tried the links below but any one of them resolves the issue:
[How to start Spark applications on Windows (aka Why Spark fails with NullPointerException)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721647/why-does-starting-spark-shell-fail-with-nullpointerexception-on-windows)

[Apache Spark error while start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085779/apache-spark-error-while-start)

[error when starting the spark shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227788/error-when-starting-the-spark-shell)

[error: not found: value sqlContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752780/error-not-found-value-sqlcontext)

The complete log of spark execution is below:

```
   D:\Spark\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin>spark-shell
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    Using Spark's repl log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults-repl.properties
    To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
    Welcome to
          ____              __
         / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
        _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
       /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
          /_/

    Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.8.0_77)
    Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
    Type :help for more information.
    Spark context available as sc.
    16/04/19 16:28:10 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have mul
    tiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/D:/Spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus
    -api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/D:/Sp
    ark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/../lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
    16/04/19 16:28:10 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JA
    R versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/D:/Spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.
    2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/D:/Spark/spark-
    1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/../lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
    16/04/19 16:28:10 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have
     multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/D:/Spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/../lib/
    datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "fi
    le:/D:/Spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
    16/04/19 16:28:11 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
    16/04/19 16:28:11 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
    16/04/19 16:28:24 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not
     enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
    16/04/19 16:28:24 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:204)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:238)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:218)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:208)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:462)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry(HiveContext.scala:461)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.<init>(UDFRegistration.scala:40)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:330)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
            at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
            at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
            at <init>(<console>:26)
            at .<init>(<console>:30)
            at .<clinit>(<console>)
            at .<init>(<console>:7)
            at .<clinit>(<console>)
            at $print(<console>)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.
    apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.
    scala:991)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:9
    45)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:9
    45)
            at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.jav
    a:582)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:557
    )
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:599)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
            ... 62 more

    <console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
             import sqlContext.implicits._
                    ^
    <console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
             import sqlContext.sql
                    ^

    scala>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue and went through a number of possible solutions as explained in the links you posted, but nothing worked at the time. By running the spark-shell command, it creates the tmp\hive directory in C: and eventually found out that there was an issue with the permissions. I have made sure that my HADOOP_HOME was correctly set up and it contained the \bin\winutils.exe, then simply moved tmp\hive under %HADOOP_HOME%\bin and restarted the command prompt. This finally resolved the issue, but do remember to run the cmd as an administrator. Hope this helps, I.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue, after investigation i observed there was the compatibility issue between **[spark version](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)** and **[winutils.exe](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)** of **[hadoop-2.x.x](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1)**.

After experiment i suggest you to use **hadoop-2.7.1 winutils.exe** with **spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7** version and **hadoop-2.6.0 winutils.exe** with **spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6** version and set below environment variables

```
SCALA_HOME  : C:\Program Files (x86)\scala2.11.7;
JAVA_HOME   : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
HADOOP_HOME : C:\Hadoop\winutils-master\hadoop-2.7.1
SPARK_HOME  : C:\Hadoop\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
PATH    : %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SCALA_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;
```

Create **C:\tmp\hive** diroctory and grant access permission using below command

```
C:\Hadoop\winutils-master\hadoop-2.7.1\bin>winutils.exe chmod -R 777 C:\tmp\hive
```

Remove **metastore_db** directory from below path if exist.

```
C:\Users\<User_Name>\metastore_db
```

Use below command to start spark shell

```
C:>spark-shell
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar issue (import spark.implicits._ not found) for windows 10.
As suggested in  the post 
I set 
1. **HADOOP_HOME**  (%HADOOP_HOME%/bin/winutils.exe - should exist)
2. **%HADOOP_HOME%/bin/winutils.exe chmod -R 777 F:\tmp\hive**  (spark-2.1.1 and winutils(hadoop 2.7.1) on same F: drive, in my case)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8ild.jpg)