# Apache spark error: not found: value sqlContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to set up spark in Windows 10. Initially, I faced [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720067/spark-fail-in-windows-console16-error-not-found-value-sqlcontext) while starting and the solution in the link helped. Now I am still not able to run `import sqlContext.sql` as it still throws me an error

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Fri Mar 24 12:07:05 IST 2017:
Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.12.1.1 - (1704137): instance a816c00e-015a-ff08-6530-00000ac1cba8
on database directory C:\metastore_db with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@37606fee
Loaded from file:/F:/Soft/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/../jars/derby-10.12.1.1.jar
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_101-b13
user.dir=C:\
os.name=Windows 10
os.arch=amd64
os.version=10.0
derby.system.home=null
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
17/03/24 12:07:09 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
Spark context Web UI available at http://10.128.18.22:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1490337421381).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import sqlContext.sql
<console>:23: error: not found: value sqlContext
       import sqlContext.sql
              ^
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id =
>   local-1490337421381).
>
> Spark session available as 'spark'.

In Spark 2.0.x, the entry point of Spark is [SparkSession](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html) and that is available in Spark shell as `spark`, so try this way:

```
spark.sqlContext.sql(...)
```

You can also create your Spark Context  like this

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

First option is my choice as Spark shell has already created one for you, so make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Spark 2.1 you'll have to use the `SparkSession` object. You can get a reference to `SparkContext` from the `SparkSession` object

```
var sSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.getOrCreate();
var sContext = sSession.sparkContext;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Cloudera and have this issue, the solution from this Github ticket worked for me (https://github.com/cloudera/clusterdock/issues/30):

> The root user (who you're running as when you start spark-shell) has no user directory in HDFS. If you create one (sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/root followed by sudo -u hdfs dfs -chown root:root /user/root), this should be fixed.

I.e. create a user home directory for the user running spark-shell. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget to import the context!

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, types}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `sqlContext` in order to access it to execute SQL statements. In Spark 2.0, you can create SQLContext easily using `SparkSession` like below.

```scala
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM sometable")
```

Alternatively, you could also execute SQL statements using `SparkSession` like below.

```scala
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM sometable")
```

Answer (score 0):

First option is my choice as Spark shell has already created one for you, so make use of it.